# save/create Entity in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am facing an issue with persisting Observation entity.

The Observation entity has a list of protocols and every protocol has 1 observer. The observer can also be created before or not, so I can have many protocols which have created observers and many protocols which have not created observers.

The desired behavior for me is if I create this observation then observers with id == null will be created and observers with id will be merged.

The issue I am facing is if I specify CascadeType.Merge I can create observation with only the observers which were created before and if I specify CascadeType.Persist/CascadeType.All, I can create observation with only the observers that were not created before.

ObservationEntity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Observation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "observation_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @OrderBy("observer ASC")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Protocol> protocols;
}
```

ProtocolEntity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Protocol {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "observer_id", nullable = false)
    private Observer observer;
}
```

ObserverEntity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Observer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    private String imoCode;
}
```

ObservationService:

```
@Service
public class ObservationService {

    @Autowired private ObservationMapper observationMapper;
    @Autowired private ObservationRepository observationRepository;

    public ObservationDTO create(ObservationDTO observationDTO) {
        Observation observationCreated = observationRepository.save(observationMapper.observationDTO2Observation(observationDTO));

        return observationMapper.observation2ObservationDTO(observationCreated);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : sk.adambarca.serverspringboot.model.entity.Interval.protocol -> sk.adambarca.serverspringboot.model.entity.Protocol
```

Comment: Is there a concrete error you get?

Comment: `org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : sk.adambarca.serverspringboot.model.entity.Interval.protocol -> sk.adambarca.serverspringboot.model.entity.Protocol`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private List<Protocol> protocols = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Its not working.